# How to SUM numbers inside alphanumeric text strings across multiple cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How can I sum values inside alphanumeric text strings across multiple cells?

For example in a row of 3 cells I want to sum the number of minutes

```
A2 = Late 6 min, 
B2 = Late 12 min, & 
C2 = Late 150 min cells arranged in a row.
```

Summing the above would give me 168.

Comment: There is no attachment, because this site does not do attachments. This site is also not a free script writing service. You need to explain what you have tried and create sample data that we can use to help YOU solve YOUR problem. Edit your question and provide these details. Then post a comment to alert your followers.

Comment: Use this formula to `{=SUM(LEFT(MID(A2:C2,6,99),SEARCH("min",MID(A2:C2,6,99))-2)+0)}` enter using Ctrl + Shift + Enter

Comment: Does the question show the literal contents or a description?  Exactly what is in each cell?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*You can use this Array formula:*

```
{=SUM(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:C2,"Late",""),"Mints","")*1,0))}
```

**Note:**

- Text, **Late** & **Mints** in the formula above are editable and `Mints` can be replaced with `min`.
- Finish the formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.

Comment: This works as long as the substitute text is an exact match, including case.  You might want to clean up the example to show `min` instead of `Mints`.

Comment: @fixer1234, thanks for the observation, I think better I edit the Note section.

Answer (score 0):

If you have flash fill (2013 and later), you can put in a helper column and use it.

Add a row above your data, insert a row and put something like "s5t3" in it, then place "9876543210" in the helper column cell next tthat, press Ctrl-E, and the numerical items from your data column will be placed in the helper column. Minus anything except numbers. Since your data only has numbers in a single place and are meant to be taken as a whole, so to speak, their counterparts in the helper column will be the data you wish to add and so on. If it must be cleansed afterwards, Paste|Values in the results cells and delete the helper column and the extra row.

However, if you can't do that, or don't want to, aren't allowed to, etc., and really need a formula, Ablebits has a formula:

```
=IF(SUM(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"}, "")))>0, SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&A1, LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$"&LEN(A1))),1))* ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$"&LEN(A1))),0), ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$"&LEN(A1))))+1,1) * 10^ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$"&LEN(A1)))/10),"")
```

(all one line, of course). Place it next to the first cell in your data (to the right, like A2 if data begins in A1). Highlight it and one other cell (that will not have any instances of "A1") and use Ctrl-H to replace "A1" with the address of your data's first cell. Or place it wherever you need the first data cell's output. If you need it inside a formula, figure out the cell address to replace "A1" with and do so, then copy and paste it into the formula.

Mmmm... wait, yours go across columns... place it under the first data cell and replace "A1" accordingly. (Or not at all in the example you give.)

In whatever case, all the digits in the source data are kept, all else is dropped, and a single number value is created. Obviously, that would be a problem for larger numbers of digits, but your data will not have those issues.

Lastly, I will point out that your data is very nicely formed so you can reliably extract the digits with this approach:

```
=MID(A1,6,FIND(" min",A1)-6)
```

Because the first digit is the 6th character in, always, and "space-m-i-n" (" min") always follows it. You begin the string at character 6 and dynamically find the character number of the space in " min", then subtract that 6 to get the length of the digit portion so the MID() function returns only the digits.

This is something that you can always use if your data is well-formed and well-characterized. And yours is, so... make it easy on yourself!

Answer (score -1):

You could use "text to Columns" to split the text and numbers then sum the numbers follow the steps below:

1. Select the cell or column that contains the text you want to split.
2. Select Data > Text to Columns.
3. In the Convert Text to Columns Wizard, select Delimited > Next.
4. Select Space.
5. The Text, Number & Text will be split into columns.
6. Select Finish.
7. Now you can =sum() the column with the numbers...

[image: Text to Column]

[image: Sum the numbers]

Comment: Farmetly, hi this method doesnt work at all as all this information I hv vlookup from different sheet it contains formula..  now I need remove the text and sum all the latenes's in min.

Comment: Then you can do another thing make a copy and past it with no format value to another worksheet.

Comment: I have found a solution for your problem please check I have attached [link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2459-excel-sum-cells-with-text-and-numbers.html)

Comment: I still can't get the sum value result return as  #value!... any other idea. I just need to sum the numbers in between text...

Comment: This works with formulas as well as actual text.  Since the values are in a row, it would benefit from copy/paste-special transpose as an intermediate step.